# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't like typedef typename in mixin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have some code that compiles fine with gcc but Visual Studio does not like. I have distilled it to a minimal example below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <Eigen/Dense>

template<class Base>
class Timestamp : public Base
{
public:
    typedef typename Base::PointType PointType;
    double timestamp;
};

/*
struct Point {};

struct PointXYZ : public Point
{
    typedef PointXYZ PointType;
};
*/

struct PointXYZ : public Eigen::Vector3d
{
    typedef PointXYZ PointType;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Timestamp<PointXYZ> point;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is `"error C2039: 'PointType' : is not a member of 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>'"`

The class PlainObjectBase is part of the Eigen library. If I replace the definition of PointXYZ with the one in comments that derives from an empty "Point" class, it compiles fine in VS as well. Any suggestions on why this is happening and what can be changed for VS to accept it as gcc does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're redefining the type member `PointType` in `Timestamp`? You're already inheriting from a type that you expect to contain the `PointType` type member, which means that `Timestamp` has the `PointType` type member as well via inheritence. If you get rid of this typedef from `Timestamp`, you shouldn't have this problem.

I'm not familiar with Eigen, but I imagine it's [this library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). If so, the documentation shows that [`Vector3d`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga2006332f6989f501762673e21f5128f5) is a typedef for [`Matrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) (i.e. a `Vector3d` is just a `Matrix`), which itself *contains* a typedef named [`Base`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html#a319e79809d439b8fabeafa27c28c8835) representing the base class `PlainObjectBase<Matrix>`:

```
typedef PlainObjectBase<Matrix> Base;
```

My guess is that when you do:

```
typedef typename Base::PointType PointType;
```

the `Base` is being evaluated as the Matrix' `Base` typedef and *not* the template type parameter `Base`, so it's effectively trying to do what your error message says:

```
typedef typename PlainObjectBase<Derived>::PointType PointType;
```

Which obviously fails because `PlainObjectBase` doesn't contain a `PointType` type member, not to mention that this isn't what you're trying to do.

Does changing the template type parameter for `Timestamp` to `B` for example resolve things?

```
template<class B>
class Timestamp : public B
{
public:
    typedef typename B::PointType PointType;
    double timestamp;
};
```

That would confirm that this is the problem, and presumably indeed a bug in Visual Studio 2010 (try later versions if you can). Personally though I would recommend simply removing the typedef, since you're already inheriting it.

Comment: You are right on both counts. I changed the name and it worked. Then I removed the typedef and it still worked. Thanks!